# JS load order - scroll JS disables, callback solution, or maybe simpler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I "think" I need a callback solution to load js files in the right order: I’m using a weeny js load script to fetch content from .php files into a page wrapper, content loads fine but the page scroll js doesn’t deploy, ceases to function, after content is loaded into the wrapper. I’ll be adding Bootstraps navbar at some point: visitors click around, fresh or changed content will load on nav menu click without refresh. Lots of changing content, lots of pages. Maybe the solution is even simpler than a callback? Grateful for any help, driving me ditzy. Teddy.
http://mauvemiracle.com/ONEPAGE/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the index.php response content on document ready in general.js, but you don't wait for the content to load before executing your function in front.js. Due to the way onepage is written you are calling a plugin on a non existing DOM element at the time of the call (your base index.html has only the #wrapper, the .main is appended when index.php finishes loading).

You can convert your immediate function in front.js into a function called init or something and call it in the callback of load once index.php is loaded as follows (i pasted your immediate function content to illustrate the idea)

```
$('#wrapper').load('wrapper/index.php', null, function () {
    // index.php content is loaded here, and the content appended
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Delay the initialisation until the event stack is clear
        onepage();
        utils();
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: My friend, you're a superstar, hours and hours I've been on this, solved instantly, so superbly simply, thank you so much.

Comment: Can be a bit sticky sometimes, doesn't always scroll after load - have to refresh, which isn't totally perfect, do I need to uncomment the 'init' ?

Comment: If someone could clarify, help get rid of the "sticky" - do I need to amend the above code in some way, thanks!

Comment: Comment out your immediate function from front.js.
And update your handle as my current edit shows.